# How to change Image in ImageView using ArrayList depending of result

Tags: arraylist, imageview

I have aplication which calculates BMI. I m trying to show diferent text and image depending of result. With text everything is fine, but I dont know what to do with ImageView.

My code:

```
    public class ResultActivity extends MainActivity {

    private String height;
    private String weight;
    //?private ImageView imageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        List<ResultModel> results = new ArrayList<ResultModel>();



        results.add(new ResultModel(16, "under weight", R.drawable.image_imc_under weight));
        result.add(new ResultModel(18, "ideal weight"", R.drawable.image_imc_ideal_weight));
        result.add(new ResultModel(25, "overweight"", R.drawable.image_imc_owerweight));
        result.add(new ResultModel(31, "obesity"", R.drawable.image_imc_obesity));
        result.add(new ResultModel(99, "morbid obesity"", R.drawable.image_imc_morbid_obesity));

        TextView tvResultIMC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_imc_tv);
        TextView tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_tv);
ImageView imageResult = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.result_image_view);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            weight= extras.getString("WEIGHT");
            heiht= extras.getString("HEIGHT");

        } else {

            weight= (String) savedInstanceState.get("WEIGHT");
            heiht= (String) savedInstanceState.get("HEIGHT");
        }
        float valueWeight;
        float valueHeight;
        int imc;


        valueWeight= Float.parseFloat(weight);
        valueHeight= Float.parseFloat(heiht)/100;
        imc = (int) (valueWeight/ (valueHeight* valueHeight));

        for(ResultModel index: results) {
            if(imc > index.getmLimit()) {



                tvResultIMC.setText(Integer.toString(imc));
                tvResult .setText(index.getRes());
    imageResult.setImageResource(index.getmImageView());
                break;
            }
        }






    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        savedInstanceState.putCharSequence("WEIGHT",weight);
        savedInstanceState.putCharSequence("HEIGHT",height);

    }
}
```

I did try to find solution and nothing. Android studio shows me errors like:

1.ResultModel() in ResultModel cannot be applied to

2.setImageResource in ImageView cannot be aplied.

Please, can someone give me an explication what im doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
In public class`ResultModel` i had to do :

1.`private int imageView;`

2.In Constructor

`this.imageView= imageView;`

3.New getter

`public int getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }`